# Can we get username auto-complete without a ping?

Tags: feature-request, chat, autocomplete

I'm frequently in the Android chatroom. Part of our rules (based on many people's preferences) is that excessive use of @User pings is forbidden/discouraged. It would be nice if there was an alternate notation I could use instead to auto-complete a user's name (or just hitting tab to trigger the autocomplete).

Comment: Have everyone install a JavaScript script that disables the sound. Problem solved!

Comment: Or people could just disable their system sound.

Comment: Sometimes people need system sound on for other reasons.

Comment: How did you guys define "excessive?"  If there are two separate conversations going on, pings are the only way to keep them straight.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think that is Carl's point. There's no need for the constant pinging even with multiple conversations if you can auto-complete the name to reference them without the sound. Some people don't want to hear that constant "ping" if they, say, have headphones on. But they would still be able to easily see the name